# Unknown error for using reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a two dimensional array that I am going to reshape into a new two dimensional array. i.e.,

```
        int array[3][2];
        int r = 3;
        int c = 2;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                array[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }

    int(*array_pointer)[r][c] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[r][c]>(array);
```

The program is not exactly like this but it serves the main point. For some reason when I pass in the ints r and c I get this error:

```
cannot initialize a variable of type 'int (*)[r][c]' with an rvalue of type 'int (*)[r][c]'
```

Now making the ints into const ints or just changing them into 3 and 2 works as well. But I need to have them be casted as ints, any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: This compiles for me.

Comment: @JakeFreeman Okay, what IDE are you using? or what is your binary parser set at?

Comment: g++ 4.8.2 through the C9 IDE.

Comment: `size_t` should be supported from C++14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first: you cannt use variables in casting, you need to re-write:

```
int(*array_pointer)[r][c] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[r][c]>(array);
```

to:

```
int(*array_pointer)[3][2] = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3][2]>(array);
```

If you need to use something more flexible or dynamic, maybe consider use std::vector

Comment: Why cannot we use variables in casting? It works if I say const int.

Comment: Yes, but it is not "really" a variable, if you want some more flexible, you cannt use it. if you want a dynamic value for r & c, use (for example) std::vector